# EclipseLink Moxy: Java type binding not working with sub-types (composition)

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I have stumbled into an issue with MOXy v2.5.1 best explained with examples below

Input:

```
<Root>
    <parentId>1</parentId>
    <parentVersion>1</parentVersion>
    <children> <!-- Always has one and only one child -->
        <child>
            <cType>P</cType>
            <cId>2</cId>
            <cVersion>2</cVersion>
        </child>
    <children>
</Root>
```

With the above XML as the base input and with the binding file given below, all java attributes especially *cType* is non-null after running the unmarshaller. So, we are good here.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
        xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
        package-name="com.xyz.model"
        xml-access-order="alphabetical" 
        xml-mapping-metadata-complete="true">
    <xml-schema/>
    <xml-java-type-adapters>
        <xml-java-type-adapter value="com.xyz.unmarshal.xml.DateAdapter" type="java.util.Date"/>
        <xml-java-type-adapter value="com.xyz.unmarshal.xml.BooleanAdapter" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>        
    </xml-java-type-adapters>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="com.xyz.model.SomeType">
            <xml-root-element name="Root"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id"                            name="parentId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="version"                       name="parentVersion"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="cType"                         name="children/child/cType"/>
                <!--xml-element java-attribute="subType"                        name="children/child" --/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="com.xyz.model.SubType">
            <java-attributes>   
                <xml-element java-attribute="subTypeId"         name="cId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="subTypeVersion"    name="cVersion"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
   </java-types> 
</xml-bindings>
```

But the moment we uncomment the *subType* attribute in the above example, all but *cType* is populated. This seems to be the case if we have anything that starts with the same name as the as the name of the *subType* attribute.

Any idea how to resolve this (I cant change the input XML for sure)?

**Update (3rd Feb):**

Have a *very bad* solution - to split the  binding files into two(in my case) and unmarshall the same message twice (expensive) using different binding files and merge the objects back. I am not at all happy with the solution that I have come up with. So either need to explore some other reference implementations or wait for this to be resolved in MOXy (ideal).

Regards.

Comment: What do your classes look like?

Comment: Hey Blaise, They are just POJO's with the properties matching that of the java-attribute names

Comment: Hey Blaise, any luck in replicating the issue?

Comment: I have added an answer.  Let me know if it makes sense.  If not I'll try to expand the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following portion of your metadata document:

```xml
<xml-element java-attribute="cType" name="children/child/cType"/>
<xml-element java-attribute="subType" name="children/child"/>
```

When you mapped the `subType` property to the `children/child` path, then it expects the domain object mapped to `child` owns what is below that element.  Since the mapping for `cType` dips below that element things are being thrown out of whack.

Comment: Thanks Blaise, that makes sense. So, what would be your suggestion/solution for a mapping with that sort of intention where parent attribute's value comes out of a child node?